# Getting a UIVIewController from a storyboard by overriding it's designated initializer

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

In Objective-C, I often override my UIViewController subclass's `init` like this

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"..." bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"..."];
    return self;
}
```

So that when I need to use it, I can simply call `id controller = [MyViewController new]`

Is it possible to do similar thing in Swift, so that I can call `let controller = MyViewController()` to get a view controller instantiated from a storyboard?

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    // you can't assign self
    self = UIStoryboard(name: "...", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("...")

    // you can't return anything other than nil
    return UIStoryboard(name: "...", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("...")
}
```

I know I can have class function

```
class func controller -> instancetype {
    return UIStoryboard(name: "...", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("...")
}
```

But calling `MyViewController.controller()` is not as straight-forward as `MyViewController()`- If I'll never use MyViewController without the storyboard, doesn't it make sense to make that the *designated* initializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing allocation with initialization.

`init` initializes an object that's been allocated.

`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` instantiates (allocates and initializes) a view controller object.

In short, the factory method is the replacement for `alloc` `init`.

Trying to call `instantiate` in `init` is like calling `[[[[Class alloc] init] alloc] init]`.  What you did (in your Objective C code) is not initialize, but discard the object that was allocated and handed to you for initialization, and replaced it with a separately allocated and initialized object.

*For readability's sake (you and others understanding the code), I'd suggest keeping init distinct from alloc.  People understand and expect `init` to initialize its object, but won't expect your `init` to be allocating its object.*

Comment: *sigh* I know you're right, but I just wish there's a way to do what `initWithNibName: bundle:` does, but with storyboard. There are just so many things that a storyboard can do but a nib can't :(

Comment: How about `awakeAfterUsingCoder`? I'm not too familiar with that method, but based on the docs it gives you a chance to return an alternative object instead of self?

Comment: This will only lead to more convoluted code.  Instead of trying to call init() and expect it to give you a storyboard view controller, call the instantiate method (with its parameters) and let it create and initialize the object for you.  Trying to get away with calling init() and having it supply parameters for you is *not* a good idea, and won't produce readable code, but it will produce code smell.